# How do I open links in a window?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I recently implemented a button in an Android application to open links externally, but I realized I can't find a way to open the link in a window.

I need it to open [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EEaZ.jpg), not [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plhrb.jpg) (look at the url bar).

Here's the piece of code I currently use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe looking for `Custom Tabs by Chrome`

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/integration-guide/